# Selenium Apache POI - What is the best way to Read Data from Excel and use that data in Test scripts

Tags: selenium, apache-poi, page-factory

I have a Page Object Model project structure. The project structure is as follows:

```
src
->com.actions
->com.config
->com.pageObjects
->com.testSuite
->com.utils
```

In `utils` package have excel class from where I read test data from excel by calling getCellData method which I have defined in excel class.

In `pageObjects` package, I have all the locators of the page using Page factory.

In `actions` package, I have the actions which needs to be done on particular page. So, here is my query - As of now, I'm getting data from excel sheet by passing row and column numbers. here is my code:

```
ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.TestData_Path + Constant.TestData_FileName,"User Info");

AdminLoginPage.username.sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(1, 0));
```

Like this I was getting data from excel till now, this will be not be feasible in long run it seems. Can someone help or suggest a best way to do the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @JeffC: The problem is, in the way i'm doing - I have to remember the row and column number for the particular data to be used in testScripts. And if the row and column increases then it will be a tedious task to update the testScripts. I want to know is there a way I can use the data dynamically without remembering the column and row numbers.

Comment: You can segregate your Test data based on the test cases. For ex: TestCaseId || StudentId || StudentName || Grade. Through this you can easily navigate to the desire TestCaseId row and fetch the details. Correct me if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @Kaustubh Atul's suggestion is what I would recommend. Have the first column be the test case name, then the rest of the columns are the other test case data. At the start of the script, pull the row where the first column matches your test case name and you're set. We do basically the same thing except we use SQL and have one row per piece of test data but each row has the test case name field that we sort by.

Comment: thanks @Atul and JeffC. My testdata is like -TestCaseID || File Format || File Name || File image|| File path. There are the columns in the excel. As per your suggestion, I should go for the particular cell say TC_01 (testcaseID) and based on that iterate the entire row and get the data? Please correct me if I get it wrong.

Comment: Indeed. This will solve your purpose.